# Excel VBA macro to change text contents in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I a would like to implement a macro to manipulate imported raw data. I have a bit of experience coding in Python but have never used VBA.

The data is as follows

```
Column A
P1
P2
P3
P3 - Paper
P2 - Paper
```

I am trying to change the text for each of these to instead say something like:

```
Column A
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 3
Product 2
```

The logic I would like to achieve is the following:

```
IF 
 A = "P1" then A = "Product 1"
Else IF 
 A = "P2" then A = "Product 2"
Else IF 
 A = "P3" then A = "Product 3"
Else IF 
 A = "P3 - Paper" then A = "Product 3"
END
```

Currently I am using another workbook with a fixed table to be able to do the comparison logic with fixed values. I would like to know if there is a way to convert the monster equation below to a macro:

```
IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$2,DropDownList!$M$2, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$3, DropDownList!$M$3, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$4,DropDownList!$M$4,IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$5, DropDownList!$M$5, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$6, DropDownList!$M$6, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$7, DropDownList!$M$7, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$8, DropDownList!$M$8, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$9, DropDownList!$M$9, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$10, DropDownList!$M$10, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$11, DropDownList!$M$11, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$12, DropDownList!$M$12, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$13, DropDownList!$M$13, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$14, DropDownList!$M$14, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$15, DropDownList!$M$15, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$16, DropDownList!$M$5, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$17, DropDownList!$M$14, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$18, DropDownList!$M$8, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$19, DropDownList!$M$4, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$20, DropDownList!$M$6, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$21, DropDownList!$M$11, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$22, DropDownList!$M$22, IF(RawDataImport!E2=DropDownList!$O$23, DropDownList!$M$23, 0))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: "I would like to know if there is a way to convert the monster equation below to a macro" Yes there definitely is. What have you tried so far? There are plenty of resources around for this type of scenario

Comment: Why not use INDEX/MATCH: `=INDEX(DropDownList!$M:$M,MATCH(RawDataImport!E2,DropDownList!$O:$O,0))`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I'm trying to write it relatively fast and I'm not familiar at all with the syntax of VBA. From what I have searched most of the times these kind of replacement logic seem to be cases of removing numbers from rows of data. If you know of a good resource for quick learning I would very much welcome it. Right not it seems quite overwhelming, hence the relatively basic question :/

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for the contribution I shall try and use this logic. Final objective of using the macro however is to "idiot proof" the sheet so it can be used by pressing one button.

Comment: @ScottCraner Index + match works, thank you for the answer.